# Mild/mildew after a water leak

Tags: water, leak, mold

We had a water leak in a pipe in a wall between the garage and a closet. We fixed the leak as soon as we noticed it, which seemed to be  a week or two after it started based off of our water usage on our utility bill. We are on a slab so we remove the wet carpet in the closet immediately and put fans in the closet for a couple of weeks to make sure everything was dry. Some things were up against that wall in the garage and I guess combined with the humidity, mold or mildew quickly formed on the baseboard in the garage. Should some mold killer spray be sufficient to spray on the spot on the baseboard and inside of the wall where the sheet rock is still open (making sure it’s 100% dry before closing it up) or should we hire pros and also open up more of the sheet rock to make sure there’s not mold/mildew anywhere inside? Like I said we caught the leak fairly quickly, fixed it right away, and pulled up carpet immediately but I’m trying to be cautious in regards to mold but also don’t want to waste money on unnecessary and excessive repairs.

Comment: Mold/mlidew likes damp, so getting everything dry is 90% of the job.  Water spreads out, so getting everything dry can be a big job.  Bleach is a good mold killer as the name brand ones.  The pros will probably just add bigger fans to the job.